# How to make a multidimensional array in Progress 4GL?

Tags: multidimensional-array, progress-4gl

There are multidimensional arrays in Progress 4GL?
If "yes", how to make this in this language.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, we don't have multidimensional arrays. But it's so easy defining a temp-table that would do the same work I don't even miss it. Simple arrays are defined using the EXTENT option when defining your variable.

Comment: Temp-Tables are the way to go for most complex structures outside of the database for Progress. In other languages that support multidimensional arrays there are almost always better options within those languages.

Comment: I agree that this could accomplish the goal. I'm curious of any downsides to using a temp-table though, and if there are, what alternatives could be used.

Comment: I can't think of any downsides, really. They're super easy to use, pretty much better to handle, because sequential reading applies to it naturally as it would a physical table, and in my opinion even make the code more readable.
I guess if I had to name something that isn't as positive, then it's probably the size, as it will most likely be larger than native variables. But then again, size usually isn't a problem for systems using Progress ABL. If it's that important to be minimalist, use a lower level programming language. Progress OpenEdge is a database-driven language.

Answer (score 2):

Progress does not have native support for multi-dimensional arrays.